# Knockout won't handle numeric array for multiple select list

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to get a numeric array to bind to my select element.  I am using a numeric array because that is what the server is returning.  I have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66Bvu/) setup demonstrating the problem.

**HTML**

```
<select data-bind="selectedOptions: EnvironmentIds" id="EnvironmentIds" multiple="multiple" name="EnvironmentIds">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Hosting</option>
    <option value="2">Internal</option>
</select>
```

**Script**

```
function IncidentViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    //Properties
    self.EnvironmentIds = ko.observableArray([1]);
}

var incidentViewModel = new IncidentViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(incidentViewModel);
```

If you simply switch to a string array like so:

```
ko.observableArray(["1"])
```

Then the code works as expected.  However, I don't want to use a string array since that isn't the type of the data.  Is there a way around this or have I overlooked something simple?

Comment: The values of the options are strings, even if they look like numbers. How important is it that `EnvironmentIds` contain numbers?

Comment: My database and controller expect numbers, so, it's fairly important I suppose.  I think I'll just create a read-only property that returns a `string[]` that I can pass over to the client so Knockout is happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout's `options` binding uses `ko.selectExtensions` to give `option` elements a non-string value. A simple custom binding can do this to the existing options.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.makeOptionsNumeric = {
    init: function(element) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(element.options, function(option) {
            ko.selectExtensions.writeValue(option, +option.value);
        });
    }
};
```

Add this to the bindings for your `select` element.

```
data-bind="makeOptionsNumeric, selectedOptions: EnvironmentIds"
```

The order is important. `makeOptionsNumeric` must run before `selectedOptions`. If you're not yet using Knockout 3.0, you'll need to give some dummy value to the binding (for example `makeOptionsNumeric: {}`).

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/gUdPq/

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
function IncidentViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    //Properties
    self.Environments = [{id: 1, name: 'Hosting'}, {id: 2, name: 'Internal'}]
    self.EnvironmentIds = ko.observableArray([1]);
}

var incidentViewModel = new IncidentViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(incidentViewModel);
```

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: Environments,
    optionsText: 'name',
    optionsValue: 'id',
    selectedOptions: EnvironmentIds" id="EnvironmentIds" multiple="multiple" name="EnvironmentIds">
</select>
```

Comment: That's one workaround I suppose, but, it's not the solution I'm looking for.  If all else fails then I'll have the server pass in an array of strings.